# Bookmark a div, then load it in a separate html file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have a page with multiple divs. Users can bookmark each div by clicking an icon. When the icon is clicked, I'm adding a **.saved-item** class to the div. I have a separate page where I'd like to show all bookmarked divs but I can't figure out how to do it properly.

Function which adds class to the div:

```
$('.bookmark').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('saved-item');
});
```

In another file, I then try to load all saved items:

```
$("#content").load( "speaking-mistakes.html #wrapper .saved-item" );
```

Unfortunately, it's not working as the addClass function is not permanent. I also tried adding the div to the localStorage, but it doesn't save the entire div layout and its content (with buttons, text, style, etc.) and I don't think that loading up localStorage with possibly hundreds of divs would be a good idea.

Is there any possibility to dynamically "move" or "export" a div from one HTML file to another HTML file?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can save only the data for the bookmarked item (its id for example) and then dynamically apply the bookmarking based on the stored data.

Comment: What is a "div" here? Normally you'd save the _data_ and re-render it however you like elsewhere. It's a bit odd to try to actually save markup. In other words, you may be asking an [xy question](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: You can only put strings in local storage. This means you can stringify and store a basic object (like here an array of ids), but not part of the DOM. Like Wais says, that is in no way necessary, all you need is to store a list of the divs, not the divs themselves. If you lend someone a movie, you don't need to make a physical copy of the disc obviously to keep track of that, just note down their name and the movie's title.

Comment: Changes made to the DOM (in the browser) will not be reflected when you use `.load()` from another page. This uses AJAX to load the content fro ma new HTTP Request. The HTTP Request will read the page from the server and this will not read  it from the browser

Answer (score 0):

It depends where the content is coming from.

These things are normally saved in a database server side. And when an icon is clicked, you can add an entry in the bookmarks table in your database.

If you want to do it through client side, you can use indexedDb or [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

So you would have an array of bookmarked ids

```
const ids = [ 1, 35, 64 ]
```

when you click an icon it can push the id to this array which is then saved into localstorage like this

```
localStorage.setItem("bookmarks", JSON.stringify(ids))
```

As an extra, if a user is signed in, you can add their user id as item 0 in the bookmarks array as a way to 'authenticate' them so when other users log in, they dont see the previous users bookmarks.

This should really be done server side for best practise